# How can I perform tasks that require a file name

Tags: git

I'm a big fan of using Git using the CLI, but I find that tasks requiring a file name are a bit of a hassle. Tasks such as `diff` and single-file checkouts that are nested in a number of files come to mind.

I'm currently writing aliases to accomplish this by using Bash aliases. Here is an example of diffing using a change index -

```
# allows diffing using file index rather than relative path
gdiff() {
    f=`git status -s | sed $1'q;d'  | cut -d' ' -f3`
    git diff $f
}
```

This way, instead of doing `git diff my/super/duper/long/secret/path/app.py` I can do `gdiff 1` (assuming file `app.py` is the first file returned in `git status`). I pretty much have aliases for each function I commonly use that require a file name.

Does Git offer a built in way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Most people just rely on filename completion to avoid manually typing out really long file paths.

Comment: That's a function, not an alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to wrap `git diff` or other `git` commands; you just want to factor out the process of retrieving a file name from `git status`.

```
file_by_num () {
    git status -s | sed $1'q;d'  | cut -d' ' -f3
}

git diff "$(file_by_num 1)"
git checkout "$(file_by_num 3)"
# etc
```

Comment: This is a much better solution. Thank you!